# Bind Custom Property using AutoMapper in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, automapper

i have implemented simple MVC3 application in which i have used AutoMapper to bind my database table to ViewMode, but i unable to bind complex ViewModel using automapper.

this is my domain class

```
namespace MCQ.Domain.Models
{
    public class City
    {
        public City()
        {
            this.AreaPincode = new List<AreaPincode>();
        }

        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DistrictID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AreaPincode> AreaPincode { get; set; }
        public virtual District District { get; set; }
    }
}
```

my ViewModel class

```
 public class CityViewModel
    {
        public CityViewModel()
        {
            this.AreaPincode = new List<AreaPincodeViewModel>();
        }

        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int DistrictID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AreaPincodeViewModel> AreaPincode { get; set; }

    }
```

in that i have one ICollection property when i trying  to map this property it show me following error

```
The following property on MCQ.ViewModels.AreaPincodeViewModel cannot be mapped:
AreaPincode
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type MCQ.ViewModels.AreaPincodeViewModel.
Context:
Mapping to property AreaPincode from MCQ.Domain.Models.AreaPincode to MCQ.ViewModels.AreaPincodeViewModel
Mapping to property AreaPincode from System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[MCQ.Domain.Models.AreaPincode, MCQ.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] to System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[MCQ.ViewModels.AreaPincodeViewModel, MCQ, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
Mapping from type MCQ.Domain.Models.City to MCQ.ViewModels.CityViewModel
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' was thrown.
```

following code stuff i have written in my Global.asax

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<City, CityViewModel>()
           .ForMember(s => s.DistrictID, d => d.Ignore())
           .ForMember(s => s.AreaPincode, d => d.MapFrom(t => t.AreaPincode));
```

please let me know how i should bind this custom collection property by using automapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom mapping between `AreaPincode` and `AreaPincodeViewModel`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AreaPincode, AreaPincodeViewModel>()
  .ForMember(...)
```

And there is no need in this row: `.ForMember(s => s.AreaPincode, d => d.MapFrom(t => t.AreaPincode))` it will be matched automatically

Answer (score 1):

When mapping to `AreaPincode` in the `CityViewModel` you need to convert from the type `ICollection<AreaPincode>` to `ICollection<AreaPincodeViewModel>`, i.e. map all elements of type `AreaPincode` to elements of type `AreaPincodeViewModel`.

To do this, create a new mapping from `AreaPincode` to `AreaPincodeViewModel`.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AreaPincode, AreaPincodeViewModel>()
...
```

Once this is in place, AutoMapper should take care of the rest. You won't even need the line

```
.ForMember(s => s.AreaPincode, d => d.MapFrom(t => t.AreaPincode));
```

because AutoMapper will figure this mapping out automagically, as the property names are equal.